# How to run a script within a package

Tags: python

I have this project structure:

[image]

I am here: `'ls'` -> `app`

I want to run `python3 app/tests/NewCoreDeploy.py` 
...however, it fails ... like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from ..controllers.DigitalOcean import DigitalOcean
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I do not understand...every directory contains a `__init__.py` file ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the PYTHONPATH you have set ?

Comment: what is this? I don't know about this

Comment: The `PYTHONPATH` environment variable tells Python where to search for modules, but setting `PYTHONPATH`  isn't the correct solution to this problem in any case.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `python3 app/tests/NewCoreDeploy.py`, Python doesn't "know" that the `NewCoreDeploy.py` file is part of the `app` package, so relative imports won't work.  There are various ways of solving this problem.

Instead of writing:

```
from ..controllers.DigitalOcean import DigitalOcean
```

You could write:

```
from app.controllers.DigitalOcean import DigitalOcean
```

But then you *would* need to set `PYTHONPATH` in order for Python to find the `app` module, like this (assuming your current directory is the parent of the `app` directory):

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD python3 app/tests/NewCoreDeploy.py
```

But honestly, just about any time you find yourself setting `PYTHONPATH` it means you're doing something wrong. In this case, you would probably (a) want to set up your project so that it can be installed (e.g. using `pip install`), and (b) investigate the use of a testing framework like [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will take care of installing your projects and dependencies into a virtual environment prior to running tests.

How to set that up is really beyond the scope of this answer, but because so many projects use exactly that setup it's very easy to find examples.